# Why is my method running twice and resetting the object value I'm trying to change?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I declare an Object called gameRooms, which contains Objects representing the rooms and their properties. Then I declare gameState and include a property for 'currentRoom.' When the game starts and I set the 'currentRoom' variable to 'Graveyard' via the `ChangeRoom()` method, it works just fine.

However, when I click a button that executes the function declared in a room's `func` property, then function writes:
"You Enter The Main Hall.
You Enter The Graveyard."
...to the window. When I check the console, I'm still in the Graveyard. Why?

JSfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/SirenKing/fz8pg05L/2/

```
    gameRooms = {
        Graveyard: {
            description: 'The graveyard is small, enclosed by tall walls. The tombstones are weathered and worn. The names are hard to make out. An abandoned shed sits in one corner. A closed door leads into the castle.',
            name: "Graveyard",
            navButtons: [
                {
                    name: "Go Inside",
                    state: "locked",
                    func: function () {
                        ChangeRoom( gameRooms.MainHall );
                    },
                    id: "tomainhall",
                },
              (etc etc etc, more rooms and buttons...)
            ],
        },
    }
```

```
    gameState = {
        State: {
                currentRoom: null,
                actionIDs: [ "wakeup" ],
                navigationIDs: [],
                inventoryIDs: [],
                globalMenuIDs: [],
                health: 100,
        }
    };
```

```
function ChangeRoom( room ) {
    gameState.State.currentRoom = room;
    Say( "You enter the " + room.name );
    UpdateNavigation( );
    UpdateActions( );
    
    return gameState.State.currentRoom;
};
```

```
function Say(content) {
    let comment = content;
    let newParagraph = document.createElement('p');
    newParagraph.textContent = comment;
    let newestParagraph = document.getElementById("narrative").appendChild(newParagraph);
    document.getElementById("narrative").id = "old";
    newestParagraph.id = "narrative";
    scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);
};
```

The HTML, and the button-constructing method, are here:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="width:40%;" id="narrative"></div>

        <div id="nav" style="top:200px; right:100px; position:fixed;">
            <label>Navigate</label>
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

```
function UpdateNavigation( ) {

    let oldNavigation = gameState.State.navigationIDs;
    console.log(oldNavigation);
    console.log("removing old nav buttons by id");
    
    for (i = 0; i < oldNavigation.length; i++) {
        // for ids in gameState.State.navigationIDs, remove the button elements by those ids
        let elem = document.getElementById( gameState.State.navigationIDs[i] );
        elem.remove();
    }
    
    gameState.State.navigationIDs = [];
    let navs = GetCurrentRoom().navButtons;
    let roomName = GetCurrentRoom().name;
    console.log( roomName, "'s navButtons are ", navs);
    console.log("building new list of nav button ids");
    
    for (i = 0; i < navs.length; i++) {
        gameState.State.navigationIDs.push( navs[i].id );
    };
    
    let currentNavigation = gameState.State.navigationIDs;
    console.log(currentNavigation);
    console.log("building nav buttons from list of ids");
    
    for (i = 0; i < currentNavigation.length; i++) {

        // for objects in room.navButtons, create new action buttons with ids of the rooms you can enter
        // add innerHTML and onclick and type to the button, then append it into the navsDiv

        elem = document.createElement("button");
        elem.innerHTML = navs[i].name ;
        elem.type = "button";
        elem.id = currentNavigation[i];
        elem.onclick = GetCurrentRoom().navButtons[i].func;
        let navsDiv = document.getElementById( "nav" );
        navsDiv.lastElementChild.appendChild(elem);
    };

};
```

Comment: You don't do anything with the second parameter passed to `Say()`.  If you want to concat the values, use `+`, not `,`.

Comment: That fixed part of the problem. Now it's showing me "You entered the Main Hall" then immediately "You entered the Graveyard." I'll update the original post.

Comment: As to why it keeps appending the value... That would be because you keep appending an element with `.appendChild()`.  So of course it will continue to append values.  For why it will not change the room; currently thinking on that one.

Comment: The button appears the run the code twice, first changing the room correctly, then changing it back to what it was.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code/html that calls the func in question.

Comment: Edited to include the associated HTML and the js that constructs the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code; `Say()` does nothing with its second parameter, and should either do so, or concatenate the parameters sent to it: `function Say(one, two) { return one + two; }` or `Say(one + two);`... But mainly, the largest problem is that you append your buttons to the `label` element.

If this element were anything but a label, your code would work without issue.  This is because the [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) element propagates click or touch events to the element(s) within it, so every time you click either of the buttons in that label element, the element clicks both buttons at once.

Thus, the simple fix is to remove the code that appends the buttons to the label:

```
navsDiv.lastElementChild.appendChild(elem);
```

Should be changed to:

```
navsDiv.appendChild(elem);
```

This of course goes the same for any code that appends buttons to the label elements.  Also relevant is your `UpdateActions()` function, where you append content to the last child... A label.

[Fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Daedalus/ukj3hL7e/2/)